# Spring Boot OAuth2, with Tomcat and nginx get error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after authenticate

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot application, it use OAuth2 authentication from WSO2 Identity Server.
When I run the aplication on Spring Tool Suit, it works, so i can sing in and use my web site.
But when I run my application on Tomcat(9.0), I try access a page, and redirect to login page, and when i try to sign in, I get the error **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

**Error Example:** When my spring boot app is runing on Tomcat, and I try to access the html page: https://domain/chat/example.html

if the user was not authenticated,
redirects to login page WSO2 Identity Server:
https://domain/is/authenticationendpoint/login.do

after login, the page redirects to the urls below, and does not redirect to url(https://domain/chat/example.html)

1. https://domain/is/oauth2/authorize
2. https://domain/chat/oauth2/authorization/wso2
3. https://domain/chat/login/oauth2/code/wso2
4. https://domain/chat/login

These pages return the error **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.

A user can authenticate, but the application redirect and go to a loop that causes the error, the loop is between the urls 1,2,3,4.

**Tomcat Log**
[image]

**Spring Boot Configurations:**

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/oauth-login")
    public String getLoginPage(Model model) {

        return "redirect:/oauth2/authorization/wso2";
    }
}
```

**ConfigSecurity.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)//abilitar seguranca nos metodos
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth-login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth-login")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/applogout");

    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8443

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.wso2.client-name=WSO2 Identity Server
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.wso2.client-id=asdasd
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.wso2.client-secret=asdasd
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.wso2.redirect-uri=https://domain/chat/login/oauth2/code/wso2
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.wso2.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.wso2.scope=openid

#Identity Server Properties
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.wso2.authorization-uri=https://domain/is/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.wso2.token-uri=https://domain/is/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.wso2.user-info-uri=https://domain/is/oauth2/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.wso2.jwk-set-uri=https://domain/is/oauth2/jwks
```

This is my git: https://github.com/Mingato/Root2

I followed the tutorial: https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/secure-your-spring-boot-application-with-wso2-identity-server-8140af8aa30b

When I run a .jar file it works but when I run a .war file on tomcat it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

After many researchs, i found my mistake. My Configurations is right, but when i run my Spring boot app on Tomcat, i have to configure my application to run on it, but there are another way, I run my app in the easiest way, I generate the .jat and execute with the command bellow

```
  java -jar myapp.jar
```

So I remove the Tomcat Server to deploy my spring boot applications.